# web scrape dynamic drop down list

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all product range in:
url='https://www.danfoss.com/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/#tab-overview'

my problem is that the html tags of the last two product neither exist in inspect nor in view page source, unless I click show more.
How can I scrape them?

here is my code:

```
a=soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"tile-group-component product-group"})
b=a.find_all("li") 
for c in b:
    d=c.find('a',href=True) 
    print(d['href'])
```

but it doesnt show the last two ones

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of getting that data, as a dataframe (scraping the API endpoint from that page):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None, 'display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://www.danfoss.com',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'referer': 'https://www.danfoss.com/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
big_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(0, 10, 5):
    payload = '{"culture":"en","currentPageId":2133,"offset":'+ str(x) + ',"pageSize":7,"tags":"int_products=valves/pvg-proportional-valves,segments=dps","types":"product,productExternalContent","sortOption":""}'
    r = s.post('https://www.danfoss.com/umbraco/Api/TagBasedGroupComponentsApi/GetProductGroupComponentItems', data=payload)
    df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['items'])
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(big_df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
id  formattedStartDate  formattedEndDate    isExternalLink  title   image   imageAltText    description startDate   endDate location    eventTypes  hasErrors   hasWarnings errors  warnings    link.newWindow  link.url
0   https://danfoss-webex-umbraco-prodblue.azurewebsites.net/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-16-proportional-valves/    None    None    False   PVG 16 proportional valves  /media/14374/pvg-16-proportional-valve.jpg  PVG 16 proportional valve   <p>Low-flow PVG 16 covers simple to complex needs. Proven technology and components for customized valve stacks.</p>    None    None    None    None    False   False   []  []  False   /en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-16-proportional-valves/
1   https://danfoss-webex-umbraco-prodblue.azurewebsites.net/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-32-proportional-valves/    None    None    False   PVG 32 proportional valves  /media/14375/pvg-32-proportional-valve-with-pve-series-7-electrohydraulic-actuators.jpg PVG 32 proportional valves  <p>PVG 32 is designed for maximum flexibility configurable as an advanced electrically controlled proportional valve. As well as a load sensing directional control valve.</p>  None    None    None    None    False   False   []  []  False   /en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-32-proportional-valves/
2   https://danfoss-webex-umbraco-prodblue.azurewebsites.net/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-100-proportional-valves/   None    None    False   PVG 100 proportional valves /media/14379/pvg-100-load-independent-proportional-valve.jpg    PVG 100 proportional valves <p>The flow-sharing technology of the post-compensated, load-sensing PVG 100 is ideal in different systems. Especially in systems where flow demand regularly pushes supply to the limits.</p>  None    None    None    None    False   False   []  []  False   /en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-100-proportional-valves/
3   https://danfoss-webex-umbraco-prodblue.azurewebsites.net/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-120-proportional-valves/   None    None    False   PVG 120 proportional valves /media/14376/pvg-120-proportional-valve-with-pve-series-7-electrohydraulic-actuator.jpg PVG 120 proportional valve  <p>Load sensing valve suitable for high flow and pressure. The PVG 120 is built to take control.</p>    None    None    None    None    False   False   []  []  False   /en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-120-proportional-valves/
4   https://danfoss-webex-umbraco-prodblue.azurewebsites.net/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-128-256-proportional-valves/   None    None    False   PVG 128/256 proportional valves /media/14391/pvg-128-256-proportional-valve.jpg PVG 128/256 proportional valves <p>For the most demanding applications, only the highest flow and the highest pressure will do. The PVG 128 and PVG 256 are made for controlling the toughest applications.</p> None    None    None    None    False   False   []  []  False   /en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-128-256-proportional-valves/
5   https://danfoss-webex-umbraco-prodblue.azurewebsites.net/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-combinations/  None    None    False   PVG combinations    /media/14378/pvg-proportional-valves-combinations.jpg   PVG combinations    <p>Danfoss offers solutions which makes it possible to combine up to four different valve families.</p> None    None    None    None    False   False   []  []  False   /en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-combinations/
6   https://danfoss-webex-umbraco-prodblue.azurewebsites.net/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-ex-proportional-valves/    None    None    False   PVG-EX proportional valves  /media/14390/pvg-ex-32-proportional-valve.jpg   PVG-EX proportional valves  <p>Our PVG-EX program is an explosion proof PVG designed to be used in Ex hazardous areas like mining and oil and gas industries. The PVG-EX shares the same features as the standard PVG. This enables stack combinations of flexible slice sections, making it possible to build valve groups meeting the exact requirements, now for use in hazardous areas.</p> None    None    None    None    False   False   []  []  False   /en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-ex-proportional-valves/
7   https://danfoss-webex-umbraco-prodblue.azurewebsites.net/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-combinations/  None    None    False   PVG combinations    /media/14378/pvg-proportional-valves-combinations.jpg   PVG combinations    <p>Danfoss offers solutions which makes it possible to combine up to four different valve families.</p> None    None    None    None    False   False   []  []  False   /en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-combinations/
8   https://danfoss-webex-umbraco-prodblue.azurewebsites.net/en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-ex-proportional-valves/    None    None    False   PVG-EX proportional valves  /media/14390/pvg-ex-32-proportional-valve.jpg   PVG-EX proportional valves  <p>Our PVG-EX program is an explosion proof PVG designed to be used in Ex hazardous areas like mining and oil and gas industries. The PVG-EX shares the same features as the standard PVG. This enables stack combinations of flexible slice sections, making it possible to build valve groups meeting the exact requirements, now for use in hazardous areas.</p> None    None    None    None    False   False   []  []  False   /en/products/dps/valves-and-actuators/valves/pvg-proportional-valves/pvg-ex-proportional-valves/
​
```

Comment: with another url='https://www.danfoss.com//en/products/dhs/valves/hydronic-balancing-and-control/manual-balancing-valves/' I replaced segments with "dhs" and int_products with "hydronic-balancing-and-control/manual-balancing-valves" but I got nowhere

Comment: That page has a different structure, of course it didn't work. It's not part of your initial question - your actual question was fully adressed by my answer. If you have a different question, then post another one. And start accepting answers, if you want to keep receiving them. @Baroo.